should we specify a tag for kernel reverse engineering?
Should kernel reverse engineering have its specific tag?
kernel and user-mode reverse engineering typically rely on different tools, different structures, different methods, so shouldn't something about kernel reverse engineering be explicitly mentioned, to make it more clear?

I personally think that user-mode and kernel reversing are very different, so we could specify a tag for anything kernel, and maybe no tag for user-mode, which is the default situation, especially for non-expert.
and of course, specify the OS in its own tag.

I agree, but shouldn't we have a windows-kernel and a linux-kernel since the techniques would be different. Then we could have tools and resources for each listed in the tag wikis

I agree, edited my answer that OS should first of all have its own tag

@amccormack: completely agree. There have to be different tags for different kernels, such as [tag:linux-kernel] and [tag:windows-kernel], because that's where the operating systems differ the most. In userland a Minix3, BSDs, Solaris and Linux are pretty similar as long as you stick with SUS/POSIX, but once you enter kernel they all have differences (despite some similarities).
